# Html.BeginForm Not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I'm trying to use some features of MVC. In practice I made this view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPasswordToken", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { rt = @Request.QueryString["rt"] })))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Reset Password non riuscito")
    <div class="container above-footer login-form">
        <div class="col-md-6" align="center" style=" margin-left:25%; margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:100px;">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ResetToken)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResetToken, new { @Value = @Request.QueryString["rt"] })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ResetToken)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Change Password" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The view is used to reset a password and i want to call the method ResetPasswordToken in AccountController when i click on "Change Password".

The AccountController is so structured, but it doesn't go to the method when i click on button:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetPasswordToken()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetPasswordToken(RecoverPasswordModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ResetToken, model.NewPassword))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("PasswordResetSuccess");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password reset token is invalid.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Please someone can help me?

Thank you very much and good holidays

Roberto

Comment: Not working properly ! What is not working  ? What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: It not call the method associated

Comment: What exactly happens? If it isn't posting then it's probably a validation error that is stopping it. Have a look at the network traffic in the browser to see if anything is being posted.

Comment: With the code you posted, It should work fine ( It will hit the HttpPost action method). Did you put a breakpoint and see whether it is hitting it ?

Comment: There aren't any validation error...i only click on change password but i doesn't go to the method...my breakpoints are in the accountcontroller...and the programma not enter there!how cani debug the client side in mvc?i'm a new programmer in mvc...sorry and thanks to all

Comment: You'll want to open the developer console on your web browser, go to the network tab, and then attempt to submit the form. You can then examine the details of the request that was formed to be sent out and see why it is failing.

Comment: Ok. Tomorrow i try...and after i write a response...in my country is late but thanks to alla for now!

Comment: You have both functions marked as POST.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: The two [HttpPost] attributes could be an issue. Remove the first one.

Comment: Also is you may be missing some other attributes like **[AllowAnonymous]** **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]**. That's just an assumption on my part.

Comment: Ok. It missing [AllowAnonymus]. Great and thank you.

Now one question. What is the best method to pass the value of the tokens in the URL to the controller without use @ Html.TextBoxFor (m => m.ResetToken, new { @Value = @Request.QueryString["rt"] }). I want to hidden this value to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two action with same name and same httppost attibute. Mark first action (without parameter) as httpget

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It missing [AllowAnonymus]. Great and thank you. Now one question. What is the best method to pass the value of the tokens in the URL to the controller without use @ Html.TextBoxFor (m => m.ResetToken, new { @Value = @Request.QueryString["rt"] }). I want to hidden this value to user.